# lost my iphone development certificates

Tags: iphone

I had everything working fine on my macbook (keychain, certificates, profiles …etc) for some reason I lost everything on my macbook including the backup of my certificates that I should use in the keychain assistant, currently I am working on installing the latest version of mac os and iphone sdk and xcode in order to develop for iphone 4. But I don’t know what should I do to restore my settings and certificates or did I lose it all or what ?  I am very confused so please advise.

i even started from sctarch and submit new certificate but with no luck

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a backup of your certificate, you should delete your old one on the portal, and follow the instructions to create a new development certificate.

After that you will have to edit and regenerate all of you development profiles, as they are tied to your certificate... just edit, select your new certificate, save and download after the portal generates the new certificate.  To avoid confusion you should probably remove everything from `~/Library/Device/Provisioning Profiles`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you installed it correctly, do a build clean all and rebuild